# Why does Selenium give a timeout exception if an element is not found?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I tried the following code snippet in the Selenium C# WebDriver. (version 2.50+). I tested it with multiple functions (By.Xpath, By.ClassName, By.CssSelector, etc.)

```
var webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 60));
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
var resultElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("NonExistingClass"));
```

Why doesn't this just return an empty collection or null or even a NoSuchElementException?I think it should not return a timeout exception.

Exception:

> "An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in
>   WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver
>   server for URL
>   http://localhost:7055/hub/session/19e937df-9d51-4624-a700-33f0ec6be98c/element
>   timed out after 60 seconds."

Comment: You have given certain time span to wait. SO driver will wait for that time and then if driver is not able to find that element on the page, it will throw timeout exception.

Comment: I removed the specified wait timespan, it throws a NoSuchElementException immediately. This is what I want. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah. You need to take care of that wait. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have provided a certain time span to wait. So driver will wait for that time and then if driver is not able to find that element on the page, it will throw timeout exception.

**Just remove specified wait timespan** to solve this problem.

*I'm posting this answer because user: Kishan Patel didn't post this as answer to this question even though his comment solves the problem.*

Comment: I'm gonna accept your answer but the real MVP is @Kishan Patel